# Is it possible to use jquery style when adding attributes in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have html form taken from api as string, i need to add onSubmit event on it, like in jquery style, Is it possible and how to do it?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

class MyForm extends React.Component {
  const htmlForm = "<form><input type='email' name='user[email]' /></form>"; // this taken from API server as string
  const reactForm = ReactHtmlParser(htmlForm);

  // i want to do like this
  reactForm.on('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitted')
  })
}
```

But it doess not work, any ideas?

Another idea in pure javascript, but doesn't work yet. There is a problem on converting pure html + javascript to react component. I don't know yet what best library to convert it.

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

class NewChatButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.newChatButtonCallback({modal: {body: 'loading...'}});

    axios.get('/users/rooms/new.json')
      .then(response => {
        const reactForm = ReactHtmlParser(response.data);

        const html = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response.data, 'text/html').body;
        const form = html.querySelector('form');
        const select = form.querySelector('select');

        form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();

          console.log('submitted');
        });

        select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();

          console.log('changed')
        })

        this.props.newChatButtonCallback({
          modal: {
            title: 'Cari Tutor',
            body: reactForm
          }
        });
      }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mainModal">
          <i className="material-icons">add</i>
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default NewChatButton;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser#transform-function) from the `react-html-parser`:

```
transform = (node, index) => {
  if (node.type === 'tag' && node.name === 'form') {
    return (
      <form
        key={index}
        {...node.attribs}
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault()
          e.stopPropagation()
          console.debug('submitted')
        }}
      >
        {node.children.map((child, i) => {
          return <child.name key={i} {...child.attribs}></child.name>
        })}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

And here is how you can `render`:

```
render() {
  const htmlForm = "<form><input type='email' name='user[email]' /></form>"
  const reactForm = ReactHtmlParser(htmlForm, { transform: this.transform })

  return (
    <>
      <div>{reactForm}</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Also, you don't need a **submit** button in a single text input form on most browsers, pressing `Enter` in the field submits it. But it's best to have one. [T.J. Crowder's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61681323/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-style-when-adding-attributes-in-react-js#comment109106192_61682140)

I have added the `Submit` button. You can hide it with `CSS` if you don't want to show it.

[Live copy on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-question-61681323-ajeets-answer-co2og?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. But I didn't quite get it. `transform` is React class method. Let me read the article and understand it. Feel free to edit my answer if you would like.

Comment: If that's in a `class` construct, then yes, it's fine -- it's not a *method*, it's a property with a function assigned to it. I was reading it as being on its own.

Comment: *"Also, you need a Submit button to submit a form."* Well, you don't **need** one in a single text input form on most browsers, pressing Enter in the field submits it. But it's best to have one. :-)

Comment: My pleasure. Great answer!

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept this answer. I uploaded another version in full code

Comment: @AjeetShah, it's not an answer, just another perspective and its not working yet, your solution is working, i don't want to spent more time for other solution, just need a working solution